# Filtering my data causes the y-axis to get screwed up

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a column chart w/ d3. I have 263 data points, and showing all columns makes the chart too crowded. To filter the datapoints, I simply grab every nth item (starting from the reverse of the array, so I ensure I get the most recent datapoint).

I define the y axis tick values to include the min and max from the *unfiltered* dataset, so the user can see the *real* min and max of the dataset. I calculate the min and max before I filter the data:

```
var v = new Array();
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
    v.push(d.close); // v holds ALL our values...before we filter them
});
yAxisValues = [Math.min.apply(null, v),Math.max.apply(null, v)];

if(data.length > 100){ // make it so that the chart isn't as crowded

        var len = data.length;
        var n = Math.round(len/100); // ideally, we want no more than 100 items

        var tempData = [];
        data = data.reverse();

        for( var k = 0; k < len; k += n ){

            tempData.push( data[ k ] );
        }
        data = tempData;
        data = data.reverse();
    }
```

However, now my y-axis is screwed up, with -0.02 showing below the x-axis. What did I do wrong? My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLnkf/1/). (To see the y-axis behave normally, simply comment out the part where I filter the data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your Y Axis **values** before the filtering, but you are still creating the **scale** on the filtered data:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height - 5, 5]);
// here is where it look at the min/max of the filtered data rather than the min/max of the original
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.close;
}));
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left').tickValues(yAxisValues);
```

If you move this part before the filtering it should be OK.

Comment: It's amazing how much time I've wasted on this problem for such a simple solution. Thanks!